# How I can work with new checkbox from ajax in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I have got ajax result with new element on page.

Checkbox is:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" uid="933518636168122368" class="flag">
```

How I can select him?

my code is not working, selector object is empty:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.flag').is(':checked')) {
        alert('checkit');
    }

    $('.flag').click(function(){
        alert('checkit');
    });
});
```

What I must to do?

Comment: If the checkbox is created dynamically you will have to use a delegate to select it. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You can apply js on response data of ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `.flag` element are created dynamically you need to use event delegation to register event handlers to these elements.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.flag').is(':checked')) {
        alert('checkit');
    }
    $(document).on('click','.flag',function(){
        alert('checkit');
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SA375/)